# Non-fixed footer at bottom, in a page with non-fixed header in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, footer

I'm trying to get the classic footer at the bottom of page. The idea is that header and footer don't be fixed, to maximize content screen. It has to work in IE8, but the following code doesn't work. The wrong part is that IE leaves a white space below `<footer>`, although in Firefox works fine.

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

header
{
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

#content
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -72px; /* To avoid white space below footer. Works in FF, but not in IE*/
    padding-top: 72px;
}

footer
{
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    background: #222;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

The html code is pretty standard:

```
<body>
    <header>...</header>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

Is there a way to stick footer at bottom without fixing it in IE8?

P.S. I'm using HTML5Shiv for `<header>` and `<footer>`

Comment: But wouldn't that be semantically wrong?

Comment: Yes it would be, I think I had a brain fart there and mixed up the head tag with header. oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't take credit for someone else's work... But this is great for accomplishing that:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Comment: No problem! That sticky footer has saved my life about 100 times!